# Null pointer exception in Java despite having initialized the varibale

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
public class GradeClass {

    String nameF;
    int[] gradesF = new int[4];
    float average;

    public GradeClass(String name, int grade1, int grade2, int grade3, int grade4) {
        nameF = name;
        gradesF[0] = grade1;
        gradesF[1] = grade2;
        gradesF[2] = grade3;
        gradesF[3] = grade4;
    }
    
    public float getAverage() {
        average = (gradesF[0] + gradesF[1] + gradesF[2] + gradesF[3] / gradesF.length);
        return average;
    }
    
        // Used to reference number of sides used in current state of die.
    public String getName() {
        return nameF;
    }
    
        // Used to reference number of sides used in current state of die.
    public int[] getGrades() {
        return gradesF;
    }
```

}

```
   else if (a == 2) {
                 System.out.println("Enter name of  "+ (a+1)  +" person. :: ");
                    nameI = keyboard.next();
                    
                    while (size < 1 || size > 4 ) {
                    System.out.println("How many grades would you like to enter? 'Max-4' :: ");
                    size = keyboard.nextInt();
                    }
                    
                    while (gradeArray[b] > 1 || gradeArray[b] > 100 ) {
                        System.out.println("Enter the " + size + " grades here :: ");
                         for(b=0; b<size; b++) {
                             gradeArray[b] = keyboard.nextInt();
                     }
                  GradeClass student3 = new GradeClass(nameI, gradeArray[0],gradeArray[1],gradeArray[2],gradeArray[3]);
                }   }   
             
             else {
                 numPersons = 0;
             }
        }
        
    
    grade1A = student1.gradesF[0] + student2.gradesF[0] + student3.gradesF[0];
    
    averageA = student1.average + student2.average + student3.average;
    
    System.out.println("Name \t\t Grade 1 \t Grade 2 \t Grade 3 \t Grade 4 \t Average \n");
    System.out.println(student1.getName() + "\t" + student1.gradesF[0] +"\t" +student1.gradesF[1]+"\t" +student1.gradesF[2] +"\t" + student1.gradesF[3] + student1.average + "\n");
    System.out.println("Average\t\t" + grade1A + "\t" + grade2A + "\t"  + grade3A + "\t"  + grade4A + "\t" + averageA + "\n");
    

    
}}
```

In my main im trying to call on another instance of a class. What it needs to do is take number of participants, there names, how many grades they have, their grades, enter all grades into an array, send the name along with the grades to gradeClass and allow for me to call and use them from there.

```
    gradeClass student1 = new gradeClass(nameI, gradeArray[0],gradeArray[1],gradeArray[2],gradeArray[3]);
```

when i try to use this it tells me i need a variable

```
    gradeClass student1;
    student1 = new gradeClass(nameI, gradeArray[0],gradeArray[1],gradeArray[2],gradeArray[3]);
```

then it tells me to initialize student1 so

```
    gradeClass student1 = null;
```

from here i get "java.lang.NullPointerException

any ideas? Error is being called at

```
    student1 = new gradeClass(nameI, gradeArray[0],gradeArray[1],gradeArray[2],gradeArray[3]);
```

Comment: Can you add the code for `gradeClass` constructor

Comment: Please provide clearer code. Your snippets don't stick along well and it's hard to deduce what your code is doing.

Comment: Null pointer exceptions can never be resolved by initializing with a value of `null`.

Comment: Can you show exactly how your code is being used? I meant that I want to see how the object is being called when the error occurs. The stacktrace should show you what line it's on. Please provide a minimal reproducible example that includes that code.

Comment: There is certainly more code in your question than is required to reproduce the error - try simplifying and removing parts as long as the error still happens, to create a *minimal* reproducible example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok i figured out what was wrong, the
GradeClass student3 = new GradeClass(nameI, gradeArray[0],gradeArray[1],gradeArray[2],gradeArray[3]);

was inside a if/else statement and wouldn't allow me to call for it outside it. I had to send it to the class inside the if/else statement and then call for it again inside the if/else statement and assign it to a new variable. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

First of all class names should start with an upper case character. Follow Java conventions.

> despite having initialized the varibale

```
int[] gradesF;
```

You have defined a variable, but the variable is null because you have not specified the size of the array.

```
    gradesF[0] = grade1;
    gradesF[1] = grade2;
    gradesF[2] = grade3;
    gradesF[3] = grade4;
```

You can't just attempt to assign values to the Array without first defining the size of the Array.

You define an Array with code like:

```
int[] gradesF = new int[4];
```

Now you can assign the 4 values in the array, using the code you have above.

Edit:

```
gradeClass student1;
student1 = new gradeClass(nameI, gradeArray[0],gradeArray[1],gradeArray[2],gradeArray[3]);
```

First of all there is no need to do that in two statements, so most people would do:

```
gradeClass student1 = new gradeClass(nameI, gradeArray[0], gradeArray[1], gradeArray[2], gradeArray[3]);
```

But the problem is that in the code you posted you never create a "gradeArray" variable and initialize it with a value. You can't just use a variable without first declaring it.

Comment: gradeClass student1; and student1 = new gradeClass(nameI, gradeArray[0],gradeArray[1],gradeArray[2],gradeArray[3]); are my issues, i did fix my array problem though. keeps telling me student1 not initialized

Comment: *i did fix my array problem* - the code you have posted is NOT fixed and will not work for the reasons given above. We can't answer a question if you don't post proper code. Only one question should be asked per posting..

Comment: i mean i fixed it in mine after you told me about it. i'll fix above now

Comment: "class names should NOT start with an upper case character" -> I assume you meant "class names MUST start with an upper case letter".

Comment: @TheSummond, I added an edit which may help. In any case your original question have been answered. Therefore this answer should be "accepted" by clicking on the checkmark beside the answer so people know the original problem has been solved. If you still have a problem then you need to ask a question with your updated code that is clear so people are not confused with your original problem. Only a single question should be asked at a time.

Comment: i have updated the code to what you and others have given me, but its still telling me student3 has not been intitialized. You may have helped me with a future problem but i'm still struggling to grasp with my current one. And if i use the GradeClass student3 = new GradeClass();   It tells me 'student3 cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: @camickr , i have 'int gradeArray[] = new int[4];' in my code as well.

Comment: I will not repeat myself again. 1) The original question has been answered. Therefore this answer should be "accepted" as described above. 2) The code posted here does NOT define the gradeArray, 3) Post a new question with a proper [mre] that demonstrates your problem. 4) don't ask two questions in one thread.

Comment: @camickr ok i figured out what was wrong, the 'GradeClass student3 = new GradeClass(nameI, gradeArray[0],gradeArray[1],gradeArray[2],gradeArray[3]);' was inside a if/else statement and wouldn't allow me to call for it outside it. I had to send it to the class inside the if/else statement and then call for it again inside the if/else statement and assign it to a new variable. Thanks for the help!